# Generar un enlace class btn a partir de un input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, entrada, href

Estoy tratando de generar un enlace (de preferencia un botón) que se genere de forma dinámica con el contenido de un input, creo haber llegado lejos modificando códigos de jquery.

El enlace que quiero es una url como esta: "index.php?orden_de_compra=" a la que se le concatena un número "index.php?orden_de_compra=900"

```js
    
   var $el = $("#url"),
    url = $el.val();
     
    var $orden_de_compra = $("#orden_de_compra"),
url2 = $orden_de_compra.val();

$el.replaceWith( $("<a />").attr({"href" : url+url2,"target":"_blank"}).html("Buscar") );
    
    $("#orden_de_compra").change( function(){
        
           var $el = $("#url"),
    url = $el.val();
     
    var $orden_de_compra = $("#orden_de_compra"),
url2 = $orden_de_compra.val();

$el.replaceWith( $("<a />").attr({"href" : url+url2,"target":"_blank"}).html("Buscar") );
    
 
});
```

```html
<input type="text"  id="orden_de_compra" placeholder="Orden de compra">

<input type="text" value="index.php?orden_de_compra=" id="url">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que con esto te servirá, como al iniciar el código ya estabas haciendo el `replace` del `input` por el `<a>` no era necesario volverlo a hacer dentro de la función `change`, simplemente debías seleccionar la nueva etiqueta y cambiar su atributo `href`.

También eliminé varias líneas de código que no necesitabas.

```js
var el = $("#url"),
url = el.val();

var url2 = $("#orden_de_compra").val();

el.replaceWith( $("<a />").attr({"href" : url+url2,"target":"_blank"}).html("Buscar") );

$("#orden_de_compra").change( function(){
    url2 = $(this).val().toString();
    $('a').attr('href', url + url2);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text"  id="orden_de_compra" placeholder="Orden de compra">

<input type="text" value="index.php?orden_de_compra=" id="url">
```

Comment: Gracias por arreglar mi codigo!

Comment: Genial, si la respuesta solucionó tu problema te invito a que la marques como aceptada para que futuros desarrolladores sepan que fue una solución correcta, además te invito a que leas [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)